# Burning smell from rear rim cantilever smooth pull brakes

Tags: rims, rim-brake, damage

Engaging the rear brake results in a burning smell and significant brake wear, so bad that within just a hundred miles or so I caused significant loss of material on a brand new pad set. Looking at the brakes after use, I find flakes of brake pad rubber stuck to/falling off of what remains, and the brake has considerably eroded.

The rim is steel. It has a gash/scratch in it that is rough. The rim also has a small dent. Interesting is that both rim pads wore down extremely quickly despite the gash/dent being only on one side of the rim. I don't think the brake is rubbing while riding, because I don't feel excess resistance, and I don't smell the burning when normally riding, only under "heavy" braking (going down a hill for a block or so). However, I did notice that one brake lever can occasionally be slow to retract; but again, extreme wear is on both pads.

I took the wheel into a shop without mentioning this issue, just asking the mechanic if he thought it was safe to ride; he said it would be fine.

[image: The damage]

Thoughts?

Comment: Photos of the rim, the brake pads' wear surface, and the brake setup would be very helpful. Also, what kind of brand new pads are they? Brake pads vary considerably in their quality and wear properties.

Comment: To check for pad rub simply lift up the bike and check if the wheels spin freely. I’d sand down the gash in the rim. If the brake struggles to retract you might have to increase spring tension or replace your cables+cable housing.

Comment: How much braking do you have to do to get the burning smell? A long descent with the need to brake to maintain control wouldn't surprise me, a single stop would be remarkable, and stop-start urban riding plausible but unlikely in most climates

Comment: @ChrisH I installed new pads and, with the bike upside down, applied brake pressure, and smelled that same burning rubber smell, so I can only assume not very much braking generates the smell. When I was testing it on the old pads, I would go down a moderately steep hill ~ 1 block long and use mainly rear brakes, and that gave a very strong burning rubber smell and considerable wear.

Comment: I'm not saying they don't exist, but I've never seen a black steel rim so I wonder of it's been painted and the paint is the problem.  On the other hand that gouge in steel would take some doing, but in (black-anodised) aluminium would be easy

Comment: @ChrisH would take some doing?

Comment: If you can get a burning smell on a bench test without a lot of pushing against the brakes, something strange is going on

Comment: "would take some doing" = "would be difficult" or would take a lot of effort (or in this case some serious bad luck)  A crash that could do that to steel would do a lot of damage to the tyre, but on this tyre we see slight scuffing that could be from the same impact.  To be absolutely sure, have you, yourself, checked  with a magnet that it's steel?

Comment: @ChrisH I can hang my fridge grocery list to my rim.

Comment: A good test.  Do you know the history of the rim in terms of both that damage (which I suspect isn't the cause of the hot brakes) and any potential painting/plating.  Paint might give more friction but not be able to handle heat.

Comment: Could you have been sold brake-pads for carbon rims?

Comment: the tire bead could mess up the magnet test.

Comment: @NathanKnutson the magnet sticks to the sides and "bottom" of the rim as well as the spokes.

Comment: @ChrisH I just noticed, when I apply brakes to the bicycle while it is resting upside down and the rear wheel is spinning, not only is there a burning smell, but also the brake pad sticks to the rim. It does not stick if I forcefully apply the brake without the wheel spinning. Also, I am noticing a fainter grey ring where the paint appears to be wearing near the top of the rim, where the brake pad first makes contact (it is not making perfect flat contact with the rim). I am then going to conclude that it is an issue with the paint. I think I'm just going to get a new wheel and try that.

Comment: It could also be an issue with very cheap brake pad material unsuited to your use. What brand/type of brake pads are you using?

Answer (score 4):

I have seen various steel-rimmed bikes experience rapid pad wear in use. I only have speculative answers, but two things that are definitely true is that most steel rim bikes come with very basic components, including brakes/pads, and also steel is harder than aluminum.

The surface irregularities will only ever hurt pad lifespan. It may be possible to mitigate them somewhat, i.e. by sanding down any rough parts of the gouge.

Probably the closest thing to a good solution is get Kool Stop Salmon compound pads, which work better on steel rims than most. While not the same thing, there are other red "extreme conditions" type pads that are extra hard and may also improve things. Ultimately riders with any kind of braking needs to speak of will be much better off on aluminum rims, but it's not always practical.

Comment: When I had steel rims I used Kool-Stop Eagle 2 dual compound, because I could get them more easily than the all-pink ones.  They were far better than cheap Shimano, especially in the wet.  But I'm not sure you want a *hard* compound on steel (strictly speaking, chrome, though  I believe stainless rims were tried)

Answer (score 3):

It's clear from the refrigerator magnet test you have steel rims.
However, in the picture the rim looks very black. The scratch looks like it goes to the metal. So, your rim is coated with something that is probably generating the burning smell. Your old brake pads "painted" a layer of rubber/plastic on your rim.

1. Clean the black stuff off your rims. I'd try some steel wool and a lot of rubbing. EDIT: The black stuff is paint, but there might be brake pad residue also. Steel wool will remove paint. If there is brake residue that won't come off using cleaners steel wool might be needed.
2. The new pad set that left a coating of rubber on your rim needs to be replaced with pads that are made of better stuff. Any well known brand name pad should work. Shimano, Kool Stop, Tektro, SRAM etc.

In the comments Avocado Surprise indicates that there are already new pads on the bike. The smell will continue until the rim is clean and then you'll be able to see if the new pads have the same problem or not.

EDIT: If you have another bike you can test your brake pads on you could find out if it's the pads or the wheel that smell.

Comment: The rims were sold to me black from a bike shop. So I don't think the black color is from the old pads.

Comment: @AvocadoSurprise Are the rims black all over? Even if they are painted black - is there rubber residue on the braking surface?

Comment: They are painted black all over, including spokes. Citrasolv rag until more clean followed by water to wipe and dried with third rag. Repeated brake test. Now it's a burnt oranges smell (this is a joke, it's still the same smell). I can try the steel wool technique later tonight perhaps, but I have a feeling then the paint will come off with it.

Comment: @AvocadoSurprise You are correct - steel wool will take off the paint. If you are sure there is no brake pad residue steel wool is not needed, this would mean that your current pads are burning.

Comment: @AvocadoSurprise Do your brake pads rub on the tire?

Comment: the brake pads do not rub on the tire either when engaged or not.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the old painted, steel wheel with a new aluminum wheel and the smell is gone.

Since the old steel wheel was perfectly clean, and since I used the same brake pad set on both the steel wheel and the new aluminum wheel, and since no other issues like tire rub are the reason, I think it must have been something to do with the black paint on the rim.